# Is a DTO with an ID property considered an Entity?

Tags: oop, entity, data-access-layer, data-transfer-objects

I am trying to clarify my understanding of a `DTO` and an `Entity` object. It seems like an `Entity` can hold it's identity even if its attributes change as long as it has an id.

Isn't it possible for Data Transfer Object also to have the same definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you mean by `Entity` here? You mean `POCO`? If yes then NO DTO and POCO both are not same. A POCO can maintain state and have it's behavior but DTO's are just for transferring the state and have no behavior doesn't maintain any behavior. See [Martin Fowler Blog on DTO](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html)

Comment: Thanks for your input, this helps give clarification to this subject.